# How to allow access to guest user for image upload on site form in custom component?

Tags: joomla-3.x, media-manager

```
<field label="FORM_FIELD_IMAGES_LABEL" 
               description="FORM_FIELD_IMAGES_DESC" 
               name="images" 
               type="media" 
               directory="com_ccomponent"

        />
```

above is media field for site (front-end) form of my custom component. As guest I'm unable to browse/upload any image. 
Is there a way i can use this field type as guest user? 
It's an access related error:

> Error
>
> You are not authorised to view this resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Some permission problem are there
Goto joomla administrator -> Custom component -> Options -> Here you can set the permission for whatever guest user can access the page.

Comment: I've set permission for Public in Create and Edit, after that I was able to browse media as guest user.